# How to increase and decrease numbers by a hundred via RepeatButton?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

You can increase and decrease numbers by **one** via following codes.

Following codes are okey.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <RepeatButton Width="100" Height="40"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnRemove" Content="Remove" Click="btnRemove_Click" />
    <TextBox Width="150" Height="40" Name="txtDisplay" TextAlignment="Center" Text="5000" MaxLength="5" />
    <RepeatButton Width="100" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

...

```
Namespace WpfApplication1

Partial Public Class MainWindow

    Public counter As Integer = 5000

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        txtDisplay.Text = (System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter)).ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        txtDisplay.Text = (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(counter)).ToString()
    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

Question:

How to increase and decrease numbers by **hundred**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    counter += 100
    If (counter > 6000) Then
        counter = 6000
    End If
    txtDisplay.Text = counter.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    counter -= 100
    If (counter < 0) Then
        counter = 0
    End If
    txtDisplay.Text = counter.ToString()
End Sub
```

There is no reason to use `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment` here since the event handlers are always executed on the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

So your question is about *thread-safe* incrementing/decrementing? You can use [`Interlocked.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb):

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtDisplay.Text = System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(counter, 100).ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtDisplay.Text = System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(counter, -100).ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Based on your sample code? Mine. In a different (multi-threaded) application? Most probably Tim's.

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz: what means best? You were already using `Threading.Interlocked.Increment`/`Decrement`. So i guess you had a reason to use this thread-safe approach. Modifying the counter-field directly is not thread safe. But it's ok if there are not multiple threads modifying it at the same time. So only you know what you need.

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz: `if counter >= 0 AndAlso counter <= 6000 Then ...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you vey much but mm8 is the first answerer. So I accepted mm8's answer.